# Unable to access HTMLCollection indexed child nodes

Tags: javascript, loops

I am attempting to **iterate over the the `HTMLCollection` returned from `getElementsByClassName`** with the function below. The console shows the `HTMLCollection` has child image nodes in the first line of the console output, shown in first lines of the console I posted below. The last 2 lines of the consle however show that accessing via index returns undefined, and null when accessed with .item(). What could be wrong with my function to prevent from reading the child nodes?

```
  static get_bitmap_promises(id, rows_pers_letter, columns_per_letter) {
    let _images = document.getElementsByClassName(id + "-font-image");
    console.log(_images);
    console.log(_images.item(0));
    console.log(_images[0]);
}
```

**Console Output Start>**

```
HTMLCollection []0: img.welcome-test-font-image1: img.welcome-test-font-image2: img.welcome-test-font-image3: img.welcome-test-font-image4: img.welcome-test-font-image5: img.welcome-test-font-image6: img.welcome-test-font-image7: img.welcome-test-font-image8: img.welcome-test-font-image9: img.welcome-test-font-image10: img.welcome-test-font-image11: img.welcome-test-font-image12: img.welcome-test-font-image13: img.welcome-test-font-image14: img.welcome-test-font-image15: img.welcome-test-font-imagelength: 16[[Prototype]]: HTMLCollection

keyframesDomObj.js:86 null

keyframesDomObj.js:87 undefined
```

Comment: Probably it's the console lazy evaluating the live collection.

Comment: To elaborate on this, at the time the code runs, the images may not exist yet. When you log a HTMLCollection to the console, it is a live reference to that object and will update as the dom updates. It is not a snapshot. You could test this theory by grabbing a snapshot and logging that instead. `console.log(Array.from(_images));` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: You guys pointed me in the right direction, as I figured out the live HTML collection indeed was biting me in the ***. Resolved by using queryselector of the element (added to document later) instead of querying document

Answer (score 0):

try `_images.childNodes[0]`. Here's the reference [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp)